# Failed to join to pandas dataframe specifying on parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I need to make an inner join of two dataframes on index

```
objectId label  
46943   1
96057   1
98476   1
121042  1
124587  1

objectId    preprocessed
3873375     [завоева, ве, мир, род, помидорчик, черр, наш,...
10805823    [российск, академ, наук, ран, призна, слов, со...
19557054    []
19750631    [зарегистрирова, куйбышев, прошедш, недел, пре...
24316030    [салат, русск, красавиц, ингредиент, курин, гр...
```

When I try to call

```
ids.join(texts, how = 'inner', on = 'objectId')
```

I get an error:

```
 KeyError: 'objectId'
```

However ids.join(texts, how = 'inner') works fine. Can't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Function `join` merge by default by indices, so if `objectId` are not columns, but index, it merge correctly.

---

If use:

```
ids.join(texts, how = 'inner', on = 'objectId')
```

it means join index to column `objectId`, if not exist, get `keyerror`.

```
ids = pd.DataFrame({
         'objectId':[1,3,5,7,10,0],
         'label':[5,3,6,9,2,4],

})

texts = pd.DataFrame({
         'objectId':[10,3,5],
         'preprocessed':[['d','ff'],['gg','dd'],['qq']],

})

print (texts)

#index from objectId column
texts = texts.set_index('objectId')
#join column ids.objectId to index texts.index
df = ids.join(texts, how = 'inner', on = 'objectId')
print (df)
   objectId  label preprocessed
1         3      3     [gg, dd]
2         5      6         [qq]
4        10      2      [d, ff]
```